# Getting error while trying to authorise user with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security, authorization, thymeleaf

Trying to block access to a dropdown menu to unauthorized users using Spring Security (not owners and not admins), passing an "owner" object - the owner of the currently viewed list:

```
<span sec:authorize="hasRole('ADMIN') or #authentication.principal.equals(#owner)">
    <form class="form-horizontal" th:action="@{/todos/{id}/add(id = ${todo.id})}" method="get">
        <select class="form-control" name="user_id" id="users">
            <option>Select collaborator...</option>
            <option th:each="user : ${users}" th:value="${user.id}"
                    th:text="${user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName}"></option>
        </select>
        <input align="right" class="btn btn" type="submit" value="Add">
    </form>
</span>
```

It works well for admins but refuses to show the list for non-admin owner even though

```
<h2 th:text="${owner.equals(#authentication.principal)}"></h2>
```

prints out true. How do i fix it? Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is related to how you compare two objects in your code: the `owner` object and the `authentication.principal` object.

You could try using the == operator, which compares the object references instead of their values.

```
<span sec:authorize="hasRole('ADMIN') or #authentication.principal == #owner">
    <form class="form-horizontal" th:action="@{/todos/{id}/add(id = ${todo.id})}" method="get">
        <select class="form-control" name="user_id" id="users">
            <option>Select collaborator...</option>
            <option th:each="user : ${users}" th:value="${user.id}"
                    th:text="${user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName}"></option>
        </select>
        <input align="right" class="btn btn" type="submit" value="Add">
    </form>
</span>
```

Comment: Replaced equals with ==, menu still only shows for administrator. Checked if the objects referenced are the same (<h2 th:text="${#authentication.principal == owner}"></h2>) - prints out true.

Comment: it's possible that the owner object is not being populated correctly. Did you check for this?

Comment: Yes, just checked, owner object has correct fields.

Comment: What output do you get when you do this:

```html
<h2>Authentication Principal: [[${authentication.principal}]]</h2>
<h2>Owner: [[${owner}]]</h2>
```

Comment: Both "authentication principal" and "owner" print out the same object.

Comment: Ok strange. One thing you could try is to ensure that the owner object is of the same type as the object that is returned by the authentication.getPrincipal() method. If this doesn't work, could you try to compare a unique identifier of the two objects.

Comment: Do you have equals and hashcode implemented for the objects that you are comparing?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else will have the same problem, i fixed it by using "th:if" instead of sec:authorize.

```
<span th:if="${(#authentication.principal.id == owner.id) or (#authentication.principal.getRole().getName().equals('ADMIN'))}">
    <form class="form-horizontal" th:action="@{/todos/{id}/add(id = ${todo.id})}" method="get">
        <select class="form-control" name="user_id" id="users">
            <option>Select collaborator...</option>
            <option th:each="user : ${users}" th:value="${user.id}"
                    th:text="${user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName}"></option>
        </select>
        <input align="right" class="btn btn" type="submit" value="Add">
    </form>
</span>
```